# Need help rigging basic low poly rifles for animation

Tags: mesh, rigging, unity

I am in the process of rigging a rifle to animate and to export to unity. However for some reason either the world location of the object im rigging does not seem to change properly, resulting in the animation being implemented in unity and subsequently teleporting.

Or the object itself tears apart and does not move as required whenever in pose mode.

The parts of the weapon are parented to a single armature bone, and I need all the parts of the weapon (that do form a solid) to move when the armature is moved.

Anyone that knows what could be the problem?

I've tried : weight painting the blue areas, parenting the side parts of the rifle (stock etc) to the main body while the body is parented to the armature